# For-loop changing values to upper or lower case depending on their length

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to make a simple JavaScript program which prompts you to enter a sentence on page load. This sentence is then split up into an array separated by a space " ".

My issue currently is that it's not converting anything to uppercase or lowercase at all. I can't seem to understand why and some help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>for-loop replacement exercise</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
        var wordString = prompt("Please enter a sentence: ", 0);
        var processedString;
        var cont = boolean(true);

        // this function is called upon page startup
        function startMeUp() {
            do {
                wordString;
                if (wordString == "") {
                    cont = boolean(false);
                }
            } while(cont);

            processString(wordString);
            document.write(processedString);
        }

        // this function is attempting to iterate through a array of strings and anything that is 4 characters long it is put to lower case  
        // otherwise if the iteration is less than 4 its put to upper case
        function processString(someInput) {
            var wordArray = someInput.split(" ");
            var lengArray = wordArray.length; 

            for (var i = 0; i < lengArray; i++) {
                if (lengArray[i] == 4) {
                    wordArray[i].toLowerCase();
                } else if (lengArray[i] < 4) {
                    wordArray[i].toUpperCase();
                }
            }
            processedString = wordArray.toString();
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body onload="startMeUp();">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wordArray[i].toLowerCase(); does not change the orginal

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this question, it fails to execute (throws errors) and also gets into an infinite loop. Fix the errors and the infinite loop before posting

Comment: markup changes, updated question to be a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the return value to the array index, rather than just calling the function and not storing it:

```
wordArray[i] = wordArray[i].toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score -1):

First your not calling `startMeUp()` so I added that. next you could simplify the code by using a `map()`.

```js
var wordString = prompt("Please enter a sentence: ", '');
startMeUp();

function startMeUp() {
  document.write(processString(wordString));
}

function processString(someInput) {
  return someInput.split(" ").map(v => {
    if (v.length == 4) return v.toLowerCase()
    if (v.length < 4) return v.toUpperCase()
    return v
  }).join(' ')
}
```

Comment: I'm amazed that you shortened it up so much, I like this answer. Thank you ^-^